# How exactly does the typical shell "fork bomb" call itself twice?

Tags: bash, command-line, fork

After going through the famous [Fork Bomb questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/159491/497359) on Askubuntu and many other Stack Exchange sites, I don't quite understand what everyone is saying like it's obvious.

Many answers ([Best example](https://askubuntu.com/a/159494/497359)) say this:

> "`{:|: &}` means run the function `:` and send its output to the `:` function again "

Well, **what exactly** is the output of `:` ? What is being passed to the other `:`?

And also:

> Essentially you are creating a function that calls itself **twice** every call and doesn't have any way to terminate itself.

How exactly is that executed **twice**? In my opinion, nothing is passed to the second `:` until the first `:` finishes its execution, which actually will never end.

In `C` for example,

```
foo()
{
    foo();
    foo(); // never executed 
}
```

the second `foo()` is not executed at all, just because the first `foo()` never ends.

I am thinking that the same logic applies to `:(){ :|: & };:` and

```
:(){ : & };:
```

does the same job as

```
:(){ :|: & };:
```

Please help me understand the logic.

Comment: Command in pipelines run in parallel, in `:|:`, the second `:` does not need to wait the first one completed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Piping doesn't require that the first instance finishes before the other one starts. Actually, all it is really doing is redirecting the *stdout* of the first instance to the *stdin* of the second one, so they can be running simultaneously (as they have to for the fork bomb to work).

> Well, What exactly is the output of `:` ? what is being passed to the other `:` ?

':' is not writing anything to the other ':' instance, it's just redirecting the *stdout* to the *stdin* of the second instance. **If** it writes something during its execution (which it never will, since it does nothing but forking itself) it would go to the *stdin* of the other instance.

It helps to imagine *stdin* and *stdout* as a pile:

Whatever is written to the *stdin* will be piled up ready for when the program decides to read from it, while the *stdout* works the same way: a pile you can write to, so other programs can read from it when they want to.

That way it's easy to imagine situations like a pipe that has no communication happening (two empty piles) or non-synchronized writes and reads.

> How exactly is that executed twice? In my opinion, nothing is passed to the second `:` until the first `:` finishes its execution, which actually will never end.

Since we are just redirecting the input and output of the instances, there is no requirement for the first instance to finish before the second one starts. It's actually usually desired that both run simultaneously so the second can work with the data being parsed by the first one on the fly. That's what happens here, both will be called without needing to wait for the first to finish. That applies to all *pipe chains* lines of commands.

> I am thinking that the same logic applies to :(){ :|: & };: and
>
> ```
> :(){ : & };:
> ```
>
> Does the same job as
>
> ```
> :(){ :|: & };:
> ```

The first one wouldn't work, because even though it's running itself recursively, the function is being called in the background (`: &`). The first `:` doesn't wait until the "child" `:` returns before ending itself, so in the end you'd probably only have one instance of `:` running. If you had `:(){ : };:` it would work though, since the first `:` would wait for the "child" `:` to return, which would wait for its own "child" `:` to return, and so on.

Here's how different commands would look like in terms of how many instances would be running:

`:(){ : & };:`

1 instance (calls `:` and quits) -> 1 instance (calls `:` and quits) -> 1 instance (calls `:` and quits) -> 1 instance -> ...

`:(){ :|: &};:`

1 instance (calls 2 `:`'s and quits) -> 2 instances (each one calls 2 `:`'s and quits) -> 4 instances (each one calls 2 `:`'s and quits) -> 8 instances -> ...

`:(){ : };:`

1 instance (calls `:` and waits for it to return) -> 2 instances (child calls another `:` and waits for it to return) -> 3 instances (child calls another `:` and waits for it to return) -> 4 instances -> ...

`:(){ :|: };:`

1 instance (calls 2 `:`'s and waits for them to return) -> 3 instances (children calls 2 `:`'s each and wait for them to return) -> 7 instances (children calls 2 `:`'s each and wait for them to return) -> 15 instances -> ...

As you can see, calling the function in the background (using `&`) actually slows the fork bomb, because the callee will quit before the called functions returns.

Comment: Question. Would `:(){ : & && : &}; :` also work as a fork bomb? You would also increase exponentially, and, in fact, you could put multiple `: &` 's in there to increase it even faster.

Comment: @JFA ` ─> $ :(){ : & && : &}; :` gives syntax error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token &&' ` .  You could do this : `:(){ $(: &) && $(: &)}; :` , But again, unlike pipeline, that won't run parallel. Which would be equivalent of `:(){: & };:` . Like to verify ? try these `time $( $(sleep 1 & ) && $(sleep 1 &) )` and this `time $(sleep 1 | sleep 1)`

Comment: Exactly, the `:(){ $(: &) && $(: &)};` is a function that is issuing a logical AND operation in the return values of the first and second instance. The problem is, since a logical AND is only true if both values are true, for efficiency only the first instance will be run. If its return value is 1 it then the second instance will run. If you want to make the fork bomb even faster I think you could just pipe more instances into the chain, like `:(){ :|:|: &}; :`

Comment: Just as a side note, many scripts use this behaviour of AND in the following situation:
Say you want to run prog2 if prog1 returns true (which in bash is 0). Instead of doing a if-statement ( `if [ prog1 ]; then; prog2; fi` ) you could just write (`prog1 && prog2`), and prog2 would only run if the return value of prog1 was true.

Comment: Ok, these are all great points. I use `&&` to call `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, and `&` at the end of the line to run in the background, but that' s a great point that they won't work together. A semicolon also does not work with the ampersand.

Comment: I agree with the post above but forking the `:|:` with `&` is the whole point of the FORK bomb even if it may be slower than recursion. Forking sets a child process with it's own address space and eats up memory and the OS process table. Since recursion is the same address space and process, would it even cause the computer to crash like forking does?